# Traveling between California and Casper, WY

Tags: california, utah, wyoming

I am traveling from San Diego to Casper, WY for Thanksgiving and am a little worried about the weather. Are there any roads I should avoid or take extra precaution with when traveling through Utah and western Wyoming?

Comment: Get snow chains, and practice putting them on while wearing gloves.

Comment: Hmm, the only spot on that route where you go over some hills is just between Salt Lake and Park City, right?

Comment: You realize that's a good two day drive, right Kendra ?!

Answer (score 2):

Unless a big winter storm comes through in the next couple of a days, the roads should be in decent shape.   But stick with the interstates as they are usually the first cleared.

Carry chains and give yourself extra time to be safe.